# Odoo 11: improving performance of computed search method (when no direct relationship exists)?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, odoo, odoo-11

I stumbled on a problem when implementing computed field search is that in specific cases, computed field search has no direct relationship (as far as I know), which means I can't write a domain to find what is computed.

In that case I had to default to very inefficient search, where I search all records and then filter accordingly.

Because I knew this search scales poorly, I made a test with ~2000 manufacturing orders (this search is done on mrp.production model). Here are some stats (`mo_search` is wrapped `self.env['mrp.production'].search` with timing decorator):

```
In [12]: len(mo_search([('main_availability', '!=', 'none')]))
func:'search' args:[([('main_availability', '!=', 'none')],), {}] took: 0.0013 min
Out[12]: 3528

In [13]: len(mo_search([('main_availability', '!=', 'released')]))
func:'search' args:[([('main_availability', '!=', 'released')],), {}] took: 0.0029 min
Out[13]: 3047

In [14]: len(mo_search([('main_availability', '=', 'released')]))
func:'search' args:[([('main_availability', '=', 'released')],), {}] took: 0.0012 min
Out[14]: 788

In [15]: len(mo_search([('main_availability', '=', 'available')]))
func:'search' args:[([('main_availability', '=', 'available')],), {}] took: 1.6445 min
Out[15]: 1460
```

So parts (Look at method `_search_main_availability`) that are optimized, finish searching in less than a second (if/elif parts) and non optimized part finishes searching in almost two minutes (else clause). So thats a huge difference and with more records it would be even slower.

Now how it looks like:

```
import operator as op

from odoo import models, fields, api, _


OPS = {
    '=': op.eq,
    '!=': op.ne,
    'in': op.contains,
    'not in': lambda a, b: not op.contains(a, b),
}


class MrpProduction(models.Model):
    """Extend to add materials main location.

    It is used to show available materials on that location which are
    demanded on manufacturing order.
    """

    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    location_main_src_id = fields.Many2one(
        'stock.location',
        "Materials Main Location",
        domain=[('usage', '=', 'internal')],
        default=_get_default_location_main_src_id)
    main_availability = fields.Selection([
        ('none', 'None'),
        ('waiting', 'Waiting'),
        ('partially_available', 'Partially Available'),
        ('available', 'Available'),
        ('released', 'Materials Released')],
        string="Materials Availability (Main Location)",
        search='_search_main_availability',
        compute='_compute_main_availability_fields',
        help="Availability of materials that are on main location.\nMaterials "
        "Released state means, there is at least one not cancelled not draft\n"
        "Transfer that was created for this manufacturing order.")

    def _search_main_availability(self, operator, value):
        # We can shortcut to non existing domain if value is falsy,
        # because every MO is expected to have truthy value.
        if not value and operator == '=':
            return [('id', '=', False)]
        if value == 'released':
            if operator in ('=', 'in'):
                # released state.
                recs = self.search(
                    [
                        ('picking_mo_ids', '!=', False),
                        (
                            'picking_mo_ids.state',
                            'not in',
                            ('draft', 'cancel')
                        )
                    ]
                )
            elif operator in ('!=', 'not in'):
                # not released state.
                recs = self.search(
                    [
                        '|',
                        ('picking_mo_ids', '=', False),
                        (
                            'picking_mo_ids.state',
                            'in',
                            ('draft', 'cancel')
                        )
                    ]
                )
        elif value == 'none':
            # Looking for none state.
            if operator in ('=', 'in'):
                recs = self.search(
                    [
                        '|',
                        ('location_main_src_id', '=', False),
                        ('move_raw_ids', '=', False)]
                )
            # Looking for not none states.
            elif operator in ('!=', 'not in'):
                recs = self.search(
                    [
                        ('location_main_src_id', '!=', False),
                        ('move_raw_ids', '!=', False)]
                )
        else:
            # THIS PART IS BOTTLENECK.
            # We can't use proper domain when checking actual
            # availability states ('waiting', 'available',
            # 'partially_available'), because domain can't tell
            # availability in this case. Instead we brute search all
            # possible MOs and then filter it accordingly.
            recs = self.search([])
            op_method = OPS[operator]
            recs = recs.filtered(
                lambda r: op_method(value, r.main_availability))
        return [('id', 'in', recs.ids)]

    def _prepare_main_availability(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        data = {}
        location = self.location_main_src_id
        if not location:
            return {}
        StockQuant = self.env['stock.quant']
        for move in self.move_raw_ids:
            product = move.product_id
            qty_available = StockQuant._get_available_quantity(
                product, location)
            qty_demand = move.product_uom_qty
            line_data = {
                'product': product,
                'qty_available': qty_available,
                'qty_demand': qty_demand,
                'qty_left': qty_available - qty_demand,
            }
            data[move.id] = line_data
        return data

    def _get_main_availability_state(self, data):
        if self.picking_mo_ids.filtered(
                lambda r: r.state not in ('draft', 'cancel')):
            return 'released'
        if not data:
            return 'none'
        if len(data) == len([i for i in data.values() if i['qty_left'] < 0]):
            return 'waiting'
        if len(data) == len(
                [i for i in data.values() if i['qty_left'] >= 0]):
            return 'available'
        return 'partially_available'
```

So `_get_main_availability_state` is used to compute value for mentioned field (`main_availability`). It used data that is generated using method `_prepare_main_availability`. So there you can see how those values are computed.

Now with search part, because field is not stored, we need to write domain for those computed values. With `released` and `none` values it is easy, because there is relationship with `mrp.production`. With other values, I don't see any relationship, so I search for all possible records and then filter it, which as I said before, scales poorly.

So does anyone know any ideas if this search could be improved?

**P.S.** If anyone wonders why I'm trying to compute and not store this field. I actually did store it with other (that has some extra functionality) related model records previously, but it had slowed down manufacturing order reservation considerably (because it would need to recreate or rewrite those records every time reservation is done). Now wit this new approach, reservation is as fast as without my functionality, but search has become a bottleneck..

Comment: I think the big bottleneck is the computation of `main_availability`. Seems you're calling stock availability for every single production, instead of doing something aggregated or more of a one shot query. Stock availability is and was always slow in Odoo. For example: never try to compute the availability of 1000 products in single shots, but instead in one big search or read, or just don't use Odoo's computed fields and just compute things you really need here by your own implemented computation.

Comment: @CZoellner well that might be problematic when field needs to be recomputed, but in search it does not need to compute anything. So I would say it is different problem.

Comment: @CZoellner but you gave good idea. I could aggregate product availability where it is possible (to call on same product per `self` records and location on compute). Then there should be less calls on `_get_available_quantity`.